# Put Column Values into combine function "c()" - R

Tags: r

How to put all values from a column into a `c()` function. For example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 200 |
| C | 300 |

How do I get all values of `Column A` into `c('A', 'B', 'C')`, without "hard-coding" the values?

I tried using `c(df$Column.A)`, but I'm not sure if this works/the best way to do this.

Comment: If there is a space in the column name, you need to surround it in backticks: ```c(df$`Column A`)``` though note that this is just the same as ```df$`Column A` ``` - it's not clear why you want `c()` here

Comment: Is the column named `Column A` or `Column.A`?

Comment: Each column of a data frame is a vector already, so if you reference the column e.g. with `df$COLUMN_NAME`, it will output the column values as a vector, which is equivalent to creating a vector with `c()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `dput()`:

```
dput(df$ColumnA)

c("A", "B", "C")
```